# Targets and multiple attacks on a full round action

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat

In DnD 3.5, depending on your base attack bonus, you can use a full round action to perform multiple attacks. I have two questions regarding to targeting:

Assuming one has two attacks:

- Can one target one foe with one attack and one with the other or does he have to attack the same opponent?
- If the first attack kills the opponent, can one attack another one?

I assume that these two are connected, and if one is true then the other is too, but is any of these two true? Of course we assume that one has sight and reach to hit both foes, and any other requirments to make these attacks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [full-attack description on the d20 SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#fullAttack):

> If you get more than one attack per round because your base attack
>   bonus is high enough, because you fight with two weapons or a double
>   weapon or for some special reason you must use a full-round action to
>   get your additional attacks. You do not need to specify the targets of
>   your attacks ahead of time. You can see how the earlier attacks turn
>   out before assigning the later ones.

The fact that it specifies that you can decide who to target for each attack after the previous attacks have been resolved means that you can target different creatures with each attack. This also explicitly allows attacking a second creature if you've killed the first one.

Note that you must still use your attacks in order from highest-to-lowest attack bonus:

> If you get multiple attacks because your base attack bonus is high
>   enough, you must make the attacks in order from highest bonus to
>   lowest. If you are using two weapons, you can strike with either
>   weapon first. If you are using a double weapon, you can strike with
>   either part of the weapon first.

Comment: It's important to note that all of the opponents you attack with a full round attack must be in range at the start of your attack.  You cannot make a movement, even a 5' step in between those attacks.  While this doesn't really matter for ranged attacks, in melee attacks this will make a difference.

Comment: @BBlake That's not what the SRD says - you still get your 5' step, but since it is a full-round action, you don't get a separate move action: _"The only movement you can take during a full attack is a 5-foot step. You may take the step before, after, or between your attacks."_

Comment: Additionally, you can still choose between a full-attack or a standard attack (and therefore make a move action) after the first attack: _"After your first attack, you can decide to take a move action instead of making your remaining attacks, depending on how the first attack turns out. If you’ve already taken a 5-foot step, you can’t use your move action to move any distance, but you could still use a different kind of move action."_

Comment: Hmm, I must have misremembered.